# Getting error as invalid url while connecting to next page using spring data rest and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Im newbie to spring data rest and angular.js , i am facing following problem while  while entering to the following page, so please help me to get out of this problem.

Getting message "invalid url" on the header while entering in to the merchandise item page, image is shown down. On the header i am getting this error.

[image]

// Actions

```
/**
 * Save merchandiseItem
 */
$scope.save = function() {
    try {
        MessageHandler.cleanMessage();
        var save;
        if( $scope.mode === 'create' ) {
            save = MerchandiseItem.create;
        } else {
            save = MerchandiseItem.update;
        }
        save($scope.merchandiseItem).then(
            function(success) {
               // MessageHandler.addSuccess('save ok');
                //$scope.merchandiseItem = success.data;

                alert('save the file, ok');
                $scope.goToMerchandiseItemList();
            },
            MessageHandler.manageError);
    } catch(ex) {
        MessageHandler.manageException(ex);
    }
};
```

thanks in advance